# HorizontalScrollView как элемент ListView . Ошибка в CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Привет! У меня проблема с реализацией списка ListView, один из элементов которого - горизонтально расположенные фото в неизвестном количестве (приходят в строке JSON с сервера). CustomAdapter следующий:

```
public class CNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<News> listNews;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;

public CNewsAdapter(Context fragment, ArrayList<News> results) {
    listNews = results;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(fragment);
    context = couponFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listNews.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listNews.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_news, null);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_text);
        holder.dateNTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_time_difference);
        holder.likesCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_likes_count);
        holder.newsLike = (AppCompatImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ib_news_heart_btn);
        HorizontalScrollView hr = (HorizontalScrollView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_news_scroll_photo);
       // LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_news_photos);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < listNews.get(position).getUrlPhotos().size(); i++) {
            holder.image = new ImageView(context);
            holder.image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            layout.addView(holder.image);
            Ion.with(holder.image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_waiting).error(R.drawable.ic_error).load(listNews.get(position).getUrlPhotos().get(i).toString());
        }
        hr.addView(layout);
        convertView = hr;

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(listNews.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(listNews.get(position).getText());
    holder.dateNTime.setText(listNews.get(position).getDifferenceTime());
    holder.likesCount.setText(Integer.toString(listNews.get(position).getLikeCount()));
    holder.newsLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_heart_filled_20);


    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView text;
    public TextView dateNTime;
    public TextView likesCount;
    public AppCompatImageButton newsLike;
```

xml-лейаут item-ов следующий:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="News!"
        android:id="@+id/tv_news_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="News description"
        android:id="@+id/tv_news_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_news_title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hs_news_scroll_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_news_text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_news_likes_count"
        > <!--        <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/ll_news_photos"
      android:isScrollContainer="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_news_likes_count"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib_news_heart_btn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ib_news_heart_btn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ib_news_heart_btn"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/ib_news_heart_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:contentDescription="Like it!" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="How many time later"
        android:id="@+id/tv_news_time_difference"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

Ну, и собственно - сам фрагмент:

```
class CNewsFragment extends Fragment {
ListView lv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_c_news_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_news_main_list);
        CNewsAdapter newsAdapter = new CNewsAdapter(view.getContext(), API.getListNews());
        lv.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
private class API {
  public static ArrayList<News> getListNews() {
        ArrayList<News> result = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkedList<String> urlPhotos = new LinkedList<>();
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40940/mrKdWrYpMYQ.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/408ee/El-e0P99_jI.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40939/asXUtRC4r_8.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40940/mrKdWrYpMYQ.jpg");
        News news = new News("uid1", "News 1!", "Description1", "2016-07-20T16:30:00.580", 103, true, urlPhotos);
        result.add(news);
        urlPhotos = new LinkedList<>();
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40940/mrKdWrYpMYQ.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/408ee/El-e0P99_jI.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40939/asXUtRC4r_8.jpg");
        urlPhotos.add("https://pp.vk.me/c625321/v625321630/40940/mrKdWrYpMYQ.jpg");
        news = new News("uid2", "News2!", "News Descript", "2016-07-20T16:30:00.580", 1000500, true, urlPhotos);
        result.add(news);
        return result;
       }
   }
```

Уже по разному пробовал поиграться с кодом, случаются три вещи:

1. Ошибка, где компилятор ругается на то что я добавляю "child" в H.S.V., а он может содержать только одного наследника
2. Ошибка : android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams 
   Пробовал также LinearLayout как основной для xml-файла, не помогает - ошибка такая же
3. Проект запускается успешно, но на нем не отображается элемент HorizontalScrollView. Хотел решить проблему вставкой фрагмента (в кач. item'a в ListView), но как понял это не приветствуется. Подскажите пути решения пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

1) Лучше покажите код ошибки. Почему Вы пробегаете циклом по картинкам не где все сэттеры вызываются, а только если convertView == null? 
2) Зачем вы каждый раз программно создаете LinearLayout? Это понятно, что HorizontalScrollView требует внутреннего layout-a, но не проще ли его поместить в разметку через xml? Тогда в адаптере в ViewHolder добавите его, и туда будете уже циклом загонять ваши картинки.

Comment: хорошо, ставлю 'LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_news_photos);' , теперь строка '                layout.addView(holder.image);
' в моем понимании приобретает другой смысл - добавляем программно фото в нужный нам лейаут. Кстати, убираю строку 'convertView = hr;' (Пытался так вызвать хотя бы только H.S.V.) . Результат - третий случай, фрагмента HorizontalScrollView не видно. Картинки рабочие, проверял в этом коде - все работает: [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363967/dynamically-add-layout-into-getview-method-of-adaptor-in-android)

Comment: вообще, адаптер переписал по коду который по ссылке, но как только начинаю добавлять другие item'ы, он перестает работать. Там решение было проще тем, что лейаут создается заново, мне же крайне желательно привязать его к существующей разметке, ну или придется все настраивать программно

Comment: Попробовал закинуть в сеттеры. Также не виден элемент

Comment: Так, а под дебагом смотрели? Может быть не виден из-за разметки? Попробуйте закоментировать другие элементы, оставив лишь HorizontalScrollView и внутренний лэйаут, чтобы добиться просто списка с картинками.

Comment: Попробовал, все инициализируется. Не могу тогда понять где ошибка в разметке, хммм

Comment: ну вот, уже проще будет искать)

Comment: android:layout_above="@+id/tv_news_likes_count - вот без этой команды стало видно, но как то теперь нужно закрепить нижний конец с отступом в 40 dp. Большое спасибо за оперативность! )

Comment: уберите layout_above у HorizontalScrollView и попробуйте у tv_news_likes_count выставить layout_below="@+id/hs_news_scroll_photo"

Comment: так и есть, дело в этом